# maven dependencies works during compile, but fails during runtime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError & java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

When I run my program on my compiler it works fine, but when I create the jar file, the maven dependencies that I'm working with fails to be referenced correctly when I run my jar file.  I can't figure out what is going on.  Can anyone help?  I provided screenshots:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
     <artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
     <version>4.4</version>
     <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
     <!--<scope>system</scope>-->
     <!--<systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\language-all-4.4.jar</systemPath>-->
  </dependency>
```

Error I'm getting during runtime:

```
$ java -jar Spellcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/languagetool/Language
    at Spellcheck.App.main(App.java:22)`Exception in thread "main"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.languagetool.Language
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Actual output with compiler:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java...
Potential error at line: "speling erroor everwhere."
Did you mean: [spelling, spewing, spieling]
Potential error at line: "speling erroor everwhere."
Did you mean: [error]
Potential error at line: "speling erroor everwhere."
Did you mean: [everywhere, ever where]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not use images of code and error messages. Copy/paste the text into your post and format as code.

Comment: Try to manually add the dependency from the POM and run mvn clean install.

Comment: I've tried to rerun mvn clean install multiple times, but my dependencies don't seem to roll over when I deploy it.  When I compile, it's referencing all my dependencies just fine, but I'm obviously missing something in my POM.xml file that I need to include for deployment, but I'm not sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need add language-en-4.4.jar to your classpath

in the same folder where is your jar add a folder "lib" with your dependencies

if your MANIFEST file (Spellcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) not contains "Class-Path: lib/language-en-4.4.jar" add classpath as argument with your dependencies separated by ";" in linux or ":" in windows

```
java  -cp "/lib/language-en-4.4.jar:/lib/other.jar" -jar Spellcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

if your MANIFEST file contains the classpath only verify the existence of lib folder an run without cp argument

```
java  -jar Spellcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, and I can't find my MANIFEST.MF file.  When I deploy, I get a: 'Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter' error, but It's specified in my POM file.  Still not sure what is going on.